# Adding Objects from a Class to another Class

Tags: c++, class, struct

```
 INPUT STDIN -> <street> <city> <house_number> <number of objects of house> <object1> <price1> .......<object-n> <price-n> (until EOF)
```

**I need to use the "add" method in the "House" Class.**
***objective**: adding the specific n objects of each House in "House" class*

This is what i did since now:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
using namespace std;

class Object {
public:
    string valuable;
    float price;
public:
    Object() : Object("",0) {}
    Object(string v, float p) : valuable(std::move(v)), price(p) {}

    string getValuable() {
        return valuable;
    }
    float getPrice()  {
        return price;
    }
};

class House{
public:
    string street;
    string city;
    uint32_t number;
    vector<Object>valuables;
public:
    House(): House("","",0){}
    House(string s,string c,uint32_t n): street(std::move(s)),city(std::move(c)),number(n){}
    string getStreet() {
        return street;
    }
    string getCity() {
        return city;
    }
    uint32_t getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
    uint32_t getValuablesSize() {
        return valuables.size();
    }
    Object getValuable(uint32_t x){
        return valuables[x];
    }
    void add(Object a){
        valuables.emplace_back(a);
    }

};

float getTotalPrice(House a) {
    float sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.getValuablesSize(); i++) {
        sum +=a.valuables[i].getPrice();
    }
    return sum;
}

int main() {

    vector<Object>obj;
    vector<House>house;
    char object[30],street[30],city[30];
    float price;
    uint32_t house_number;
    int n;
    while(cin>>street>>city>>house_number>>n) {
        house.emplace_back(string(street),string(city),house_number);
        Object a;
        for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
            cin>>object>>price;  
            obj.emplace_back(object,price);
            a.valuable=object;
            a.price=price;
            for(int k=0;k<house.size();k++)
            house[k].add(a);          
        }      
    }
    for(int i=0;i<obj.size();i++){
        cout<<obj[i].getValuable()<<" "<<obj[i].getPrice()<<endl;
   } // trying to print the object vector
    for(int i=0;i<house.size();i++){ //trying to verify if i have the correct input
        cout<<house[i].getStreet()<<" "<<house[i].getCity()<<" "<<house[i].getNumber()<<" ";
        for(int j=0;j<house[i].getValuablesSize();j++) {
            cout << house[i].valuables[j].valuable<< " "<<house[i].valuables[j].price<<" ";
        } 
        cout<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

That's what i think:
-when i read   <house_number>  ,read the objects and prices and then the add method should be used in order to have the `vector<Object>valuables` usable.
***It's necesarly to check if the input is stored corectly in the class "House", in order to continue summing the objects in every house***

Comment: Side note, you should prefer `std::string` to `char[]` in most cases

Answer (score 1):

With the statements

```
for(int k=0;k<house.size();k++)
    house[k].add(a);
```

you add the current "valuable" object to every house that has been created thus far.

I suggest you instead create the house object separately, then add the valuable objects to the current house, and after that add the house to your collection of houses.

Perhaps something like:

```
std::string street;
std::string city;
unsigned house_number;
unsigned n;

while(std::cin >> street >> city >> house_number >> n) {
    House current_house(street, city, house_number);

    std::string object;
    float price;

    for(int i = 0; i < n && std::cin >> object >> price; ++i) {
        Object a(object, price)
        current_house.add(a);
    }

    house.push_back(current_house);
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, it worked! i didnt think like that, but good to know from now, cause 1 week ago i just started learing OOP